# how to continuously display time in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I have some code to control some buttons for an interface, but I would like to add a small text label that continuously displays time by hh:mm:ss. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

well, i think you should take a look at some cocoa development related books or websites - like [cocoadev](http://cocoadev.com/) [cocoadevcentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/) [cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/) ...

in short:
define your

```
IBOutlet NSTextField* timeLabel;
```

in your controller class and hook it up to the `NSTextField` in your `NIB`.
take a look at `NSDate` and update it (via a `NSTimer` or your draw loop)

Comment: Take a look at NSDateFormatter too. Bindings and properties could be used to solve this too. In addition to diditos recommendations I would add Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (3rd Edition)
By Aaron Hillegass.